# A finite sum with cosines

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I'm not able to compute the following sum :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(kx)}{(\cos(x))^k}$$

Comment: The answer is quite simple:
$$(n+1)\left(\frac{\cos kx}{\cos^k x}\right)$$
I suspect you want to sum over $k$ and not $i$, of which the summand is independent.

Comment: yes, i corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\cos(kx) = \Re(e^{ikx})$.  Can you use a geometric series argument to do the calculation?

Comment: i tried that way but didn't get something out. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Pull the $\Re$ out of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos(kx)}{\cos(x)^k}=\frac{(e^{-ikx}+e^{ikx})}{2\cos(x)^k}=\frac{1}{2}((\frac{e^{-ix}}{\cos(x)})^k+(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)})^k)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}((1-i\tan(x))^k+(1+i\tan(x))^k)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(kx)}{\cos(x)^k}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n(1-i\tan(x))^k+(1+i\tan(x))^k$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}((1-i\tan(x))^n+(1+i\tan(x))^n)+\frac{i\cot(x)}{2}((1-i\tan(x))^n-(1+i\tan(x))^n)$$

Comment: kk, ty for your answer!

Comment: Yea no problem lol